# How to assign two gravity attributes to view

Tags: android, xml, layout

How can I assign my Textview to align its text to be centre with regards to vertical orientation(gravity=centre_vertical), AND that the text be on the right side of the view(gravity=right)?

Answer (score 1):

In your XML use `android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"`